# AzureWebApp: Monitor Application Logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

I'm building an Azure web-app and if there are certain unexpected errors, I want to be able to bubble it up in the Azure Dashboard / add alerts.

Any `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError()` messages are logged to the `ApplicationLog`. Is there a  way to add alert/monitoring-graphs for these in Azure Portal?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use the question for an answer (as the name suggest). You should post it as a separate answer or edit an existing answer (and mark it as the accepted answer). This is just confusing.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for calling it out Dawid. I've posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aram's links below really helps. Please read them.

**To Get this working:**

1. Add the `ApplicationInsights` to your project.
2. (Optional) If you want log traces (`System.Diagnostics.Trace`) to be searchable on insights, add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` nuget to your project.
3. Use `telemetryClient.TrackException()` to place a server exception
   when you hit a critical error.
4. Add an alert on Azure portal to check for `ServerExceptions` within the given time window.

Answer (score 0):

I think and most flexible option for configuring alerts on Web Apps is enabling the Application insights have the App Insight be one of your event sources:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-search-diagnostic-logs/

Once you have the Application Insight setup then you can easily set any kind of alerts based on the diagnostics that are collected:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-alerts/

Comment: [Update]: I installed AppInsights and traceListener to get the traces to show up in AppInsights Search. Still trying to figure out how to add alerts on TRACEs.

Comment: @VigneshMurugesan Nice, the second link will show you how to add alerts.

Comment: I used TrackException() to raise telemetry exceptions and added Insights alert on them on azure portal. The frequency of these is expected to be small so Insights free tier works.

Thanks Aram. Your answer lead me to it.